# how to pass a string a variable as column name in container.dataitem

Tags: c#, data-binding

I have a databinder as shown below:

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.August") %>
```

now depending on condition i want to pass the column name (august) as parameter ie

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.monthname") %>
```

where monthname may be august,june,july or something.

i am binding this to a hyperlink.
this is a c# web application..plz help me

Answer (score 3):

You could use a method that returns the string expression the `DataBinder` should use; the method should also accept your data item object, so that you can place there your condition logic too.

For example (markup):

```
 <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, Foo(Container.DataItem))%>
```

And (code):

```
 protected string Foo(object dataItem)
 {
     if (YOUR_CONDITION_HERE)
     {
         return "NAME_OF_PROPERTY1";
     }
     else
     {
         return "NAME_OF_PROPERTY2";
     }
 }
```

Comment: Sir i tried your answer.i am getting an error                     DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'System'.                                                  plz help me its urgent

Comment: I am passing the month name as getmonth("August")                  protected String getmonth(object dataitem)
        {
            String strmonth = dataitem.ToString();
            return strmonth;
        }                                                                      <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, getmonth(Container.DataItem))%>

Comment: You should place your conditional logic inside the `Foo()` method and then return the **name of the property** you are going to bind to.

I am going to edit my answer with a better example.